# Propel ORM can't filterBy when field value contains / or \

Tags: php, database, orm, doctrine, propel

I'm trying to find a record based on values of `field1` and `field2`. This is my query

```
$rec = RecQuery::create()->filterByField1($field1)
                         ->filterByField2($field2)
                         ->findOne();
```

$field2 could have strange characters sometimes. For some reason whenever $field2 contains a `\` or `/`, propel can't retrieve the record and returns an empty result.

If I do this (get ALL records based on field1 only, then loop to match field2), then it works fine and is able to retrieve it

```
$recs = RecQuery::create()->filterByField1($field1)->find();
foreach ($recs as $rec){
   if($rec->getField2() == $field2)
         //found the record
   }
}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: How do you give `$field2` its value? What database do you use? This is probably an escaping bug, but I don't know who is supposed to escape the value (probably Propel).

Comment: @Jan Fabry I'm using MySQL. The value of $field2 is auto-generated from my within my code (not user input), and it saves fine everytime, no problems. Not sure why the filterByField2 doesn't work. I agree that it should be Propel's job to take care of escaping. I thought Propel takes care of all that through the PDO layer. At least, that's what I thought, and is why I'm using Propel in the first place (for the PDO layer) and I don't escape my user input at all because I'm depending on Propel doing that. Have you tried and found similar results?

Answer (score 0):

Propel should still be escaping OK, even if there are slash characters in a string.

Can you grab the SQL it is running (when you get your empty resultset) and see what the problem is from there? Add it to your question if that doesn't shed any light on it for you.